# What algorithm does STL size() use to find the size of a string or vector?

Tags: c++, string, stl

Which algorithm or idea does the STL `size()` function use to find the size of string or vector in C++?

I know that working of `strlen()` is dependent on finding the `NUL` character in the C-style char array, but I want to know how the `size()` function works to find the size of string that is not null terminated, as we know.

Do STL containers use some sort of pointers to mark the ending of container?

And does that help in finding the size or something else?

Comment: `size()` is required to be a constant-time operation.

Comment: There is no algorithm. There's just a variable that tracks the number of items in a container.

Comment: The algorithm is "return stored value".

Comment: on what condition does the tracking stops as there is nothing like a reference or null character?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: As far as I know, no algorithm is specified, and a `string` or `vector` may or may not store its size. As long as the size can be computed in constant time, the implementation can do anything it likes. It might retrieve a stored length, or it might retrieve a size in bytes and divide by the element size, or it might do a pointer subtraction.

Comment: @user3677837: What "tracking"? There *is no* tracking. It knows how much stuff you put into it. There's no algorithm; it's basically a variable stored in the class that keeps track of how much stuff you put in it.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Storing the size in a member variable within the object is certainly a plausible implementation, but it's not the only possible approach.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I said "basically".

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't use any algorithm. The class knows its size at all times.

Answer (score 1):

The standard doesn't specify *how* `size()` is calculated, only that the calculation is done in constant time (for example, computing the size of a 1000-element vector doesn't take 10 times as long as computing the size of a 100-element vector).

The specific algorithm might vary from one implementation to another. There might be a hidden member variable within the class that stores the current size, and `size()` simply retrieves its value. Or it might store the size in bytes, and `size()` retrieves that and divides by the element size. Or the object might store pointers to the beginning and end of the sequence, and `size()` could then compute the size using pointer arithmetic.

All you need to know, and all you should care about, is that `size()` gives you the number of elements, and it's no more expensive for large strings/vectors than for small ones. (Unlike `strlen()` which, as you point out, is slower for longer strings.)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the case `size()` will be implemented  something like

```
size_t A::size() {
    return len;
}
```

where `A` is a class and `len` is a data member of class. Hence constant time. 
Secondly, some implementation might use `pointer arithmatics` which will still be constant time algo.
Whenever possible, I will go with first approach

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/), you will see that the time complexity of both `std::vector.size()` and `std::string.size()` run in constant time. This is because vectors store two pointers, `vector.begin()` and `vector.end()`. To find the size of the vector (or string), they just subtract the two to find the size.

> Returns the number of elements in the container, i.e. `std::distance(begin(), end())`.

Answer (score 0):

[Vector implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h)

```
    // [23.2.4.2] capacity
      /**  Returns the number of elements in the %vector.  */
      size_type
      size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
```

It just subtracts the finish index - start index to get the size.